# When direction for a parameter of a TStoredProcedure is pdOutput?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, stored-procedures, ado, delphi-xe8

I am using Delphi XE8 and SQL Server 2014.

Consider the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp2_BaseShow_By_Id](
    @ShowId int,
    @Result int OUT
)
```

I use this Delphi code to enumerate its parameters:

```
function TDBHelper<T>.OpenSingle(ProcedureName:string; Args: TArray<Variant>;
  Transform: TTransformFunc<T>): TDBResult<T>;
var
  Con:TADOConnection;
  Proc:TADOStoredProc;
  ArgIndex,ParamIndex: Integer;
begin
  Result:=TDBResult<T>.Create;
  Con:=GetConnection;
  Proc:=TADOStoredProc.Create(nil);
  try
    try
      Proc.Connection:=Con;
      Proc.ProcedureName:=ProcedureName;
      Proc.Parameters.Clear;
      Proc.Parameters.Refresh;
      ArgIndex:=0;
      for ParamIndex := 0 to Proc.Parameters.Count-1 do begin
        if(Proc.Parameters[ParamIndex].Direction in [pdInput,pdInputOutput])then begin
          Proc.Parameters[ParamIndex].Value:=Args[ArgIndex];
          Inc(ArgIndex);
        end;
      end;
      Proc.Open;
      Result.Data:=Transform(Proc);
      Result.Success:=True;
      Proc.Close;
      Con.Close;
    except
      on E:Exception do begin
        Result.Success:=False;
        Result.E:=E;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Proc.Free;
    Con.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This tells me that the parameters have the following [parameter direction](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TParameterDirection):

1. `pdReturnValue` for the result of the stored procedure.
2. `pdInput` for the first parameter of the stored procedure.
3. `pdInputOutput` for the second parameter of the stored procedure.

I am surprised by item 3 in the above list. I would have expected `pdOutput`. Questions:

- Why is this parameter `pdInputOutput` rather than `pdOutput`?
- In what circumstances would a parameter be deemed to be `pdOutput`?

Comment: My question is: when your post is question? <sarcasm off> I sincerely have no idea what you're asking. The title of your question seems to ask when something happens, and the text seems to demonstrate when it happens.

Comment: I also am wondering what question you are asking. Ah, OK I guess you are wondering why the second parameter is `pdInputOutput` and not `pdOutput`. Is that it?

Comment: By the way, `E` is destroyed when the `except` block completes. But you retain a reference to the object. That is a runtime error in waiting. You need to use `AcquireExceptionObject` to avoid that happening. I can't really see the point of calling `Close` when you are about to call `Free`, and I do wonder why you bother catching the exception at all. You aren't meant to swallow exceptions.

Comment: I mean what should I do in my storedprocedure in sqlserver to have a pdOutput paramter in Delphi when looping it's parameters? in what situation we have just pdOutput not pdInputOutput?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks for the tip for the Exception.

Comment: I re-wrote the question so as to make it clearly ask what I think you want to be asked. I know nothing whatsoever about database programming so I hope that I've not made any errors in terminology or understanding.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks for the edit.

Comment: You should get the param type directly from database. I don't think you can get the param type in this way. Proc.Parameters are used to define the parameter's type, direction, etc, not to 'read' them as you are doing it.

Comment: @RBA I have tested this code. it enumerates storedProcedure's parameters correctly and worked perfectly. if it is wrong how should I call the SP and fill it's argumants? I asked this question to know is there any way to avoid calling DB_BaseShow.OpenSingle('usp2_BaseShow_By_Id',[ShowId,0],RowConvertToBaseShow); and instead call DB_BaseShow.OpenSingle('usp2_BaseShow_By_Id',[ShowId],RowConvertToBaseShow); with one less parameter. because currently I have to use the first call.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680913(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Loghman Your question concerning calling `OpenSingle` with only 1 value in the `Args` array is substantially different to what you asked. If that was your concern, you should have originally made a point of stating so clearly in your question. As it stands, you may want to ask a new question now that I have answered your original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this parameter `pdInputOutput` rather than `pdOutput`?

Because in spite of the `OUT` keyword, the parameter is used for both input and output. Try the following:

```
CREATE PROC DoubleIt (@Value int OUT)
AS
SET @Value = @Value * 2
GO

DECLARE @Val int = 3
exec DoubleIt @Val OUTPUT
PRINT @Val
```

You'll notice that `@Value` is used as both input and output.

> In what circumstances would a parameter be deemed to be `pdOutput`?

You may be able to manually create the parameter as such. Unfortunately I cannot easily test this at the moment. There is also a possibly of other database platforms supporting it.

> What should I do in my stored procedure in SQL Server to have a `pdOutput` parameter in Delphi?

I don't think there's anything you can do in SQL Server. I'm not aware of any way to define a parameter as **output-only**.

Comment: re your edit to the question. I merged the final two questions as I felt they asked the same thing. You've now quoted a question that has been removed. How is *In what circumstances would a parameter be deemed to be pdOutput?* different from *What should I do in my stored procedure in SQL Server to have a pdOutput parameter in Delphi?* ?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I originally added the 3rd question because I deemed your decision to roll the special case question into a general one to be somewhat ill-considered. As can be seen, each question has an diametrically opposing answer. ... I have no intention of getting into an edit war with you on the original question. Nonetheless, I'll leave my answer to the 3rd question in place on the basis that it was clearly asked in comments.

Comment: Clearly I don't want an edit war. I was explaining my reasoning. I can't tell the difference between the two questions. I don't understand how it can be both impossible to define an output parameter, and possible to create it manually. Clearly I am not understanding something. I won't make any more edits, and hope that you can clear it up.